# Finding the first positive number in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-in-loop, for-of-loop

I want to show the first positive number in the array in the console blog, but according to my code, it displays the second one, which is 6. Please provide an answer to my problem and give an explain of how my code works.

```js
let values = [-1, 5, -6, 6, -10, -5, 3, 4, -1, 8, 1, -10, 3];
  for (const number of values) {
            if (values[number] >= 0) {
                console.log(number); break;
            }
        } //6

        for (const key in values) {
            if (values[key] >= 0) {
                console.log(key);

            }
        } //6`enter code here`
```

Comment: Need to use `number>0` instead of `values[number]>0`

Comment: Keep it simple: `console.log(values.find(n => n > 0))`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `of` it will return the element value,so you need to use `number >= 0` instead of `values[number] >= 0`

Or you can use `in` to do it,in this case,you need to use `values[number] >= 0` rather than `number >= 0`

```js
let values = [-1, 5, -6, 6, -10, -5, 3, 4, -1, 8, 1, -10, 3];
       for (const number of values) {
            if (number >= 0) {
                console.log(number); break;
            }
        } //5
        
       for (const number in values) {
            if (values[number] >= 0) {
                console.log(values[number]); break;
            }
        } //5
        
        console.log("----------------------------")
        for (const key in values) {
            if (values[key] >= 0) {
                console.log(key);

            }
        } //6`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate it with for loop with an index

```js
let values = [-1, 5, -6, 6, -10, -5, 3, 4, -1, 8, 1, -10, 3];
  for (var i = 0; i<values.length; i++) {
            if (values[i] >= 0) {
                console.log(values[i]); break;
            }
        } //6
```

Answer (score 0):

Condition should be `number >= 0` instead of `values[number] >= 0`

Demo **:**

```js
let values = [-1, 5, -6, 6, -10, -5, 3, 4, -1, 8, 1, -10, 3];

for (const number of values) {
  if (number >= 0) {
    console.log(number);
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this simple for loop to find first positive number

```
let values = [-1, 5, -6, 6, -10, -5, 3, 4, -1, 8, 1, -10, 3];
  for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
      if(values[i]>=0){
          console.log(values[i])
          return
      }
  }
```